# Sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2^n+2^{n+1})^2}{5^{n-1}+5^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2^n+2^{n+1})^2}{5^{n-1}+5^n}$$

How should I get the sum to infinity? I tried using to find |r| but I am unsure how to do so. Can I have hints on how to approach this qn?

Comment: Were you asked to compute the sum or just say if it's convergent?

Comment: You can write the summand as $k'k^n$ where $k$ and $k'$ are two constant, then think again about classical sequences.

Comment: I was asked to compute the sum itself. I was able to tell that it is convergent by using ratio test. With the limit for An+1/An to become 4/5 < 1. However, I am unsure how to calculate the sum to infinity even tho I know it converges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(2^n+2^{n+1})^2}{5^{n-1}+5^n}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{2^{2n}+2^{2n+2}+2^{2n+2}}{6\cdot5^{n-1}}=6\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac45\right)^{n-1}=6\cdot5=30$$

Answer (score 3):

Just note that

$$\frac{(2^n+2^{n+1})^2}{5^{n-1}+5^n} = \frac{9 \cdot 4^n}{6 \cdot 5^{n-1}} = \frac{15}{2} \cdot \left(\frac 45\right)^n. $$

Comment: You forgot the square...

Comment: @DonThousand right!